# how to merge two dimensional arrays in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to merge the following two 2D arrays `A` and `B` into one 2D array `C` using C++ code. I tried to fill the array `C` with array `B` first and array `A` afterwards, but it's not working.

```
int A[3][2]={{1,2},
             {4,5},
             {7,8}};

int B[3][1]={{0},
             {4,},
             {7,}};

int C[3][3] =
        { { 0, 1 ,2},
         { 4, 4, 5},
          {7 ,7 ,8}}
```

The code I am using is:

```
// merge part
for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(i<1)
            {
                C[i][j] = B[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                C[i][j] =A[i-1][j] ;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\C: "<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout<<C[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard algorithm `std::merge` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int A[3][2] =
    {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 4, 5 },
        { 7, 8 }
    };

    int B[3][1] =
    {
        { 0 },
        { 4 },
        { 7 }
    };

    int C[3][3];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        std::merge( std::begin( A[i] ), std::end( A[i] ),
                    std::begin( B[i] ), std::end( B[i] ), 
                    std::begin( C[i] ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : C )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 
4 4 5 
7 7 8
```

Comment: I am getting following compiler error when i am running the code you have given sir
Line 27: error: 'begin' is not a member of 'std

Comment: @AjayThakur Did you include header <iterator>?

Comment: @AjayThakur In any case you may substitute for example std::begin( A[i]] ) and std::end( A[i] ) for A[i] and A[i] + 2 and std::begin( B[i] ) and std::end( B[i] ) for B[i] and B[i] + 1

Answer (score 0):

Merging two 2D arrays in one code is as follows

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
  int i,j, a[5][5]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
  int b[5][5]={26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};

int c[10][5];

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{c[i][j]=0;
}}
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
if(i<=4)
  c[i][j]=a[i][j];
if(i>=5)
c[i][j]=b[i-4][j-5];

}  
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{cout<<c[i][j]<<"\t";
}cout<<endl;
}
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```